# Loading Fragments using reflection causes "java.lang.IllegalAccessError: Class ref in pre-verified class resolved to unexpected implementation"

Tags: android, android-fragments, reflection

I am developing android Enterprise application where i want to use some file on run-time.I am able to use simple class using **Java Reflection** and i also want to use Fragment.
E.g.- I have created **TestingDummyJar.jar and placed in SDCard**. 
Usage - First I am loading this jar using DexClassLoader and then loading class. **its working perfectly for Simple class as -**

```
final File tmpDir = this.getDir("dex", 0);
classloader = new DexClassLoader("/SDcard/TestingDummyJar.jar", tmpDir.getAbsolutePath(), null, this.getClassLoader());
mLoadedClass = (Class<Object>) classloader.loadClass("com.example.testingdummyjar.TestingDummyReflection");<br>
```

**But when i try to load Fragment as-**

```
mLoadedClass = (Class<Object>) classloader.loadClass("com.example.testingdummyjar.ImageParticularFragment");
```

throw Exception **"java.lang.IllegalAccessError: Class ref in pre-verified class resolved to unexpected implementation"**

Can anyone tell me that Is it possible to load fragment from Jar file??
if yes then please give me some clue how to do that??

**Found the Solution** Seeking for some help.
The fragment which i am trying to load from jar file is using **android.support.v4 library** and my application where i want to use is also using **android.support.v4 library**. But Library is needed in both application because of fragment used in both application.
So I want to remove **android.support.v4 library**. Could you Please Help me to get rid of it??

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: would it be easier if you load the activity that uses that fragment?

Otherwise get the fragment manager and then adding/replacing the new fragment. Then getting the instance of fragment using findFragmentByTag/Id

Comment: @RusheelJain Fragment available in .jar file and i want to load that fragment So I can add/replace in my activity. –

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Android Studio, or otherwise are using Gradle, change the scope of dependencies shared between the main app and the JAR you are loading via `DexClassLoader` to `provided` instead of `compile`.

In your case, both the app and the JAR depend upon `support-v4`. In the app, use `compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:24.2.0'` as normal. In the JAR, use `provided 'com.android.support:support-v4:24.2.0'`.

This does not seem to be required on Android 5.0+, probably due to ART. On 4.4 and older, Dalvik gets irritated if both the app and the JAR have the same classes. Switching to `provided` says "compile against these classes, but do not package them in the library, as we will get our implementation of those classes from elsewhere". In this case, the JAR gets the implementation from the app's classloader (`this.getClassLoader()`).

Comment: Gradle will not let me switch to `provided` because `Provided dependencies can only be jars. [Android library]@aar is an Android Library.` Thoughts?

Comment: @KennethWorden: AARs contain resources, a manifest, and perhaps assets, and those all have to be dealt with at compile time. Hence, `provided` does not work.

Comment: I was perusing this issue all day and saw that older versions of the Android/Gradle plugins allowed this behavior. Can you speak to this?

Comment: @KennethWorden: Really? That would surprise me greatly, as I have no idea how it could work. If I had to guess, somebody ran into a problem with it, filed an issue, and they tightened down `provider`.